# Statistics Homework Question (Binomial Distribution)

Tags: statistics

**Problem:** In a binomial experiment with 45 trials, the probability of more than 25 successes can be approximated by $P(z > \frac{(25-27)}{3.29}$)

What is the probability of success of a single trial of this experiment?

**Choices:**

- 0.07
- 0.56
- 0.79
- 0.61
- 0.6

**My Solution:** 
Since the experiment can be approximated by a normal distribution, I evaluated P(z) using NormalCdf on my calculator. $$P(z > \frac{25-27}{3.29}) = NormCdf(\frac{25-27}{3.29},\infty, 0, 1) = 0.72834 $$

Then, I set up the binomialCdf expression as $binomCdf(45, p, 26, 45)$ using 26 as the minimum number of successes as the question specifies it to be more than 25.

**Through inspection, I found p to be 0.61**. However, the answer key says otherwise.

Can someone check the error in my work? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're saying that 
\begin{align*}
P(\text{Binom$(45,p)$} > 25) &\approx P(N(0,1) > \frac{25-27}{3.29}) \\
&= P(N(27,3.29^2) > 25)
\end{align*}
So the binomial is approximately equal in distribution to a $N(27,3.29^2)$ random variable. Setting the expected value in terms of the parameters of the binomial equal to the mean of the normal approximation, we have
\begin{align*}
E(\text{Binom$(45,p)$}) = np = 45 \cdot p \approx 27
\end{align*}
So $p \approx 27/45 = 0.6$

Answer (score 1):

When approximation a binomially distributed variable by means of the normal distribution one gets:

$$\mu = \frac{np}{\sigma} = \sqrt{np(1-p)}$$

Now $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$, so $\mu = np = 27$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = 3,29$.

Thus $\sigma = \sqrt{27(1-p)} = 3,29$ and solving yields $p=0,6$.